# Strange crashes on Zenbook UX31A with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, lightdm, asus, cinnamon

I'm facing some strange crashes. I initially installed 13.04 on my Asus Zenbook UX31A and used Cinnamon as my preferred desktop environment. After upgrading to final version 13.10 I'm not able to start any desktop environment correctly from LightDM.

First I thought this is due to a kernel bug as mentioned in many bug reports, forums, blogs and so on. But choosing other kernels (3.8, 3.10) in grub didn't solve my problem.

Trying to boot up with Unity: After some seconds and a black screen I just get back to LightDM. Trying to boot up with Gnome Flashback: Icons are visible (with default theme) on a black background desktop without panel and window manager (no window borders). Same with Cinnamon (which is a fork of Gnome Shell).

I looked into syslog, dmesg, Xorg.0.log but can't find any helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

As no one can provide a solution and I need to work with my computer I did a fresh install. 13.10 + Cinnamon 2 works just fine here. I guess something went wrong with the packages.